# Type Error when Comparing Two Dictionaries Using Cosine Similarity in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, cosine-similarity

I have received a type error while comparing two dictionaries using the cosine similarity. I have tried to search around but still not able to solve it, and would really appreciate if anyone could shed some light for me.

My dictionaries look as like below.

```py
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
dict2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
```

I have also looked around in stack overflow, and indeed there are members who also compared the values of dictionaries using cosine similarity. And I thought it should be very similar to my case. This is the url where I referenced to: [Python: calculate cosine similarity of two dicts faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381939/python-calculate-cosine-similarity-of-two-dicts-faster)

This is the function as provided by @Davidmh (with slight modifications to it):

```py
import numpy as np

def cos(v1, v2):
    up = 0
    for key in set(v1).intersection(v2):
        v1_value = v1[key]
        v2_value = v2[key]
        up += v1_value * v2_value
    if up == 0:
        return 0
    return up / (np.sqrt(np.dot(v1.values(), v1.values())) * np.sqrt(np.dot(v2.values(), v2.values())))
```

So the next thing I did is to call the function:

```py
print(cos(dict1, dict2))
```

And below is the type error message that I received.

```py
File "C:/Users/Yoshiaki/TextProcessing/compute.py", line 157, in cos
    return up / (np.sqrt(np.dot(v1.values(), v1.values())) * np.sqrt(np.dot(v2.values(), v2.values())))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'
```

I have googled on the type error that appeared, but it doesn't gives me much explanation nor result. And it seems to do with set operations...? I also tried even without using the set operation (intersection), it will also give me the same error message...

Could anyone please advice to me of how I could solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try changing them to lists via list(v1.values())? dict_values is a type, so converting it to a list may solve the issue.

```
return up / (np.sqrt(np.dot(list(v1.values()), list(v1.values()))) * np.sqrt(np.dot(list(v2.values()), list(v2.values()))))
```

Reference:
[Python: simplest way to get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/python-simplest-way-to-get-list-of-values-from-dict)